# Passing contents of file as argument into C++ program

Tags: c++

Using C++, need to pass the contents of a file to the program as an argument à la `$ ./main <filename.txt` or `$ echo the contents of the file | ./main`

I want to be able to access the contents of the file as a variable or something so I can manipulate further.

I have this basic listing including some of the stuff I've been trying.  The data doesn't seem to be in `argv` (my runs always tell me I have one argument).  What is the way to access a command line argument passed in this way?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << "Have " << argc << " arguments:" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
    std::cout << argv[i] << std::endl;
  }
  std::istream* input = &std::cin; 
  if(argc > 1) {
    std::cout << input;
    std::cout << "more than argument found\n";
  }

  std::string inputs;
  std::cout<< "1:\n";
  std::cout<< argv[0];
  std::cout<< "\n2:\n";
  std::cout<< argv[1];
  std::cout<< "\n3:\n";
  std::cout<< input;

  std::cout<< "\nEnd\n";

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

I perhaps wasn't entirely clear, given it was a fairly fundamental question I was asking but didn't realize.  Essentially, passing using `$ ./main <filename.txt` is non-negotiable. User [RPGillespie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2516916/rpgillespie%20%22rpgillespie%22's)'s comment pointed me in the right direction.  The pipe sends it to `stdin` (which I didn't realize).  Thus I wanted to handle the data using `cin`.  A minimal working example would be

```
int main() {
  // read input
  for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no lanuage called C/C++

Comment: The pipe sends it to `stdin` (i.e. you would need to use `cin` to retrieve it), I think you want `xargs`

Answer (score 4):

`cat file | ./main` will pipe the file content to the **input** of the `./main`, *not* the argument.

If you want to pipe arguments in this way, use `xargs`:

`cat file | xargs ./main`

Answer (score 2):

While @liliscent has a great solution, the following also works (I am mentioning it for the sake of completeness and since I feel it is more readable):

```
./main $(cat file)
```

This takes the contents of the file called `file` (since it interprets the command inside the `$(` and `)`), and passes them as arguments to `./main`.